# How to generate a random 2D array of integers, such that x,y = y,x? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm working on a travelling salesman solver, and I'd like to be able to randomly generate the matrix that represents the distances between cities. Here's an example of what I've been using so far:

```
distances = [[0, 3, 7, 1, 6, 2],
             [3, 0, 9, 2, 8, 7],
             [7, 9, 0, 5, 4, 8],
             [1, 2, 5, 0, 4, 9],
             [6, 8, 4, 4, 0, 4],
             [2, 7, 8, 9, 4, 0]]
```

What can I use to write a function that creates an `x`*`y` matrix of random integers where `distances[x][y]` = `distances[y][x]`? (Bonus if the element = 0 when `x`=`y`)

Comment: Does it matter that purely random values may violate the triangle inequality? i.e. they might create a situation where *(distance from A->C) > (distance from A->B) + (distance from B->C)* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a symmetric matrix.
You can make symmetric matrices by:

```
import numpy as np
N=5  # dimension of your matrix
b = np.random.randint(0,3000,size=(N,N))  #0 and 3000 are the range of numbers you want in your matrix
mat = (b + b.T)//2

print(mat)
array([[2510,  684, 1990, 1121, 1710],
      [ 684, 2920, 2245, 2620,  564],
      [1990, 2245,  934, 1439, 1790],
      [1121, 2620, 1439, 2075, 2288],
      [1710,  564, 1790, 2288,   13]])
```

Finally, If you want to fill the elements of diagonal to 0 then:

```
np.fill_diagonal(mat, 0)

print(mat)

array([[   0,  684, 1990, 1121, 1710],
       [ 684,    0, 2245, 2620,  564],
       [1990, 2245,    0, 1439, 1790],
       [1121, 2620, 1439,    0, 2288],
       [1710,  564, 1790, 2288,    0]])
```

Comment: `0 and 3000 are the range of numbers you want in your matrix` then why there is `4679` which is present in final array?

Comment: It might not matter for OP's use case, but using `b + b.T` means the distribution of values is not uniform here. It's for the same reason that the sum of two dice rolls is not a uniform distribution on [2, 12].

Comment: @Daweo I am getting numbers greater than range specified as I am doing `(b + b.T)`. Now, I have edited my code to `mat = (b + b.T)//2`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking look at [`tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) or [`triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) function, you might getter lower or upper triangle and combine with transposition e.g.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(6,6))
distance = np.where(np.triu(arr)==0,np.triu(arr).T,np.triu(arr))
print(distance)
```

might give output

```
[[25 36 22 32 80 33]
 [36  3 19 51 24  8]
 [22 19 47 98  6 46]
 [32 51 98 24 28 40]
 [80 24  6 28 29 12]
 [33  8 46 40 12 66]]
```

Explanation: I generate 6x6 random array, then get upper triangle, everything outside that triangle is zero, so I use [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get value from transposed upper triangle where there is zero.

**Disclaimer**: this solution provides just that `distances[x][y] == distances[y][x]`, no attempt is done to make `distances[x][x] == 0`

Comment: Specify `k=1` in `np.triu` to obtain `distances[x, x] == 0`, and I suggest caching the results of `np.triu`, as its cost is not small.

Comment: Instead of `np.triu(arr) == 0`, consider using [`np.tri`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also possible by generating only enough random numbers as necessary:

```
import numpy as np

N = 6     # Number of cities
M = 10    # One more than the maximum distance

# Generate random integers only for one 'half' of the matrix
size = N * (N - 1) // 2
nums = np.random.randint(M, size=size)

distances = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=nums.dtype)
tri = np.tri(N, k=-1, dtype=bool)

distances[tri] = distances.T[tri] = nums
```

results

```
>>> distances
array([[0, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8],
       [4, 0, 6, 7, 5, 7],
       [1, 6, 0, 2, 5, 6],
       [2, 7, 2, 0, 2, 3],
       [8, 5, 5, 2, 0, 3],
       [8, 7, 6, 3, 3, 0]])
>>> np.all(distances == distances.T)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `random` module in Python to generate random integers for your distance matrix. To ensure that distances[x][y] is equal to distances[y][x], you can generate a lower triangular matrix and then reflect it across the diagonal.

Example

```
import random
from pprint import pprint


def generate_distance_matrix(size):
    """Initialize an empty matrix"""
    distances = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]

    # Generate random distances for the lower triangular matrix
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(x):
            # Modify the range as per your requirements
            distances[x][y] = random.randint(1, 10)  # 

    # Reflect the distances across the diagonal
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(x + 1, size):
            distances[x][y] = distances[y][x]

    return distances


if __name__ == '__main__':
    matrix_size = 6
    distances = generate_distance_matrix(matrix_size)
    pprint(distances)
    # [[0, 5, 8, 10, 7, 2],
    #  [5, 0, 5, 2, 3, 9],
    #  [8, 5, 0, 1, 2, 10],
    #  [10, 2, 1, 0, 5, 8],
    #  [7, 3, 2, 5, 0, 8],
    #  [2, 9, 10, 8, 8, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

From an array of city "pseudo-positions", a simple broadcast of differences in absolute value should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

cities = np.random.randint(0,100,(5,))            # 5 cities 0..100 apart
distances = abs(cities-cities[:,None])

print(distances)     #        3   80   28   39   59
[[ 0 77 25 36 56]    #  3 [[  0,  77,  25,  36,  56]
 [77  0 52 41 21]    # 80  [-77,   0, -52, -41, -21]
 [25 52  0 11 31]    # 28  [-25,  52,   0,  11,  31]
 [36 41 11  0 20]    # 39  [-36,  41, -11,   0,  20]
 [56 21 31 20  0]]   # 59  [-56,  21, -31, -20,   0]]
```

*Note that those are not "physical" distances in a Cartesian plane.  Also, this approach creates an additive pattern where for some A,B,C cities A->C is equal to A->B + B->C which may or may not be something you want/need.*

If you want to avoid the additive pattern, you can combine (add) transposed triangular matrices of random distances. Each value will be added to a corresponding zero in the transposed copy:

```
distances = np.triu(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)),1) 
distances = distances+distances.T

print(distances)
[[ 0 23 46 76  9]   # [[ 0 23 46 76  9]      [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [23  0 48 94 37]   #  [ 0  0 48 94 37]       [23  0  0  0  0]
 [46 48  0 93 71]   #  [ 0  0  0 93 71]   +   [46 48  0  0  0]
 [76 94 93  0 33]   #  [ 0  0  0  0 33]       [76 94 93  0  0] 
 [ 9 37 71 33  0]]  #  [ 0  0  0  0  0]]      [ 9 37 71 33  0]]
```

If you want to only generate the exact number of random distances and you plan to produce multiple test cases in the same matrix, you could setup the indices and counts once and perform the random distance generations in one line when you need it:

Setup:

```
N = 5

distCount = N*(N-1)//2                 # total number of random distances
iDist     = np.triu_indices(N,1)       # indices of upper part of matrix
distances = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=int)  # will receive random distances
```

Random matrix generation:

```
distances.T[iDist] = distances[iDist] = np.random.randint(0,100,distCount)

print(distances)

[[ 0 41 49 56 49]
 [41  0 22 85 21]
 [49 22  0 12 22]
 [56 85 12  0 21]
 [49 21 22 21  0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem using pure python like this:

```
import random

def generate_symmetric_matrix(n, min_dist=1, max_dist=10):
    matrix = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i] = random.randint(min_dist, max_dist)
    return matrix
```

or you can also solve it using numpy like so:

```
def generate_symmetric_matrix(n, min_dist=1, max_dist=10):
    i_upper = np.triu_indices(n, 1) # indices for upper triangle of matrix excluding diagonal
    matrix = np.zeros((n, n)) # create nxn matrix filled with zeros
    random_values = np.random.randint(min_dist, max_dist, size=len(i_upper[0])) # generate random values
    matrix[i_upper] = random_values # assign random values to upper triangle
    matrix.T[i_upper] = random_values # assign same random values to lower triangle using transpose
    return matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, yet working solution:

```
import numpy as np

size = 5  # shape of 2d array is (size,size)
array = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(size, size)) # Generate a random 2D array
array = (array + array.T) // 2 # Make the array symmetric
np.fill_diagonal(array, 0) # Set diagonal elements to 0

print(array)
#     Gives
# [[0 8 5 4 4]
#  [8 0 6 2 5]
#  [5 6 0 3 8]
#  [4 2 3 0 3]
#  [4 5 8 3 0]]
```

Comment: This answer is already present

Comment: @GodIsOne, I didn't notice your answer